# Find all questions that I flagged to close?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, profile-page

How should I find all questions that I vote for close ? I saw a `closure` tag in vote tab, but doesn't seem to have the closed ones, only up/downs, also, is there a search command for that

Comment: I'm not sure I understand if you want to find questions you've voted to close (you can't yet, so you don't have any, but you've found the place where those go), find questions that you have asked and that have been voted to close (don't think there's anything for that), or questions that you have asked and have been closed (there's a search operator for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have enough reputation to vote to close, you've probably [flagged](https://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/flag-posts) to close. You can see a [history of your flags](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/11318) in your profile, linked next to your avatar below your email address, date of last visit and other personal details.

Answer (score 1):

If by "closure tag in vote tab", you mean [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/11318/warl0ck?tab=votes&sort=closure):

[Screenshot of the closure subtab http://so.mrozekma.com/votes-closure.png](http://so.mrozekma.com/votes-closure.png)

that's the right place. That lists all (undeleted) posts that you've voted to close. I would expect yours to be nearly empty, since you don't have [enough rep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions) to close posts, but you might have a couple votes to [close your own posts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/view-close-votes)